# Compare against median of each column

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns, median, operation

How can I compare against median of each column in a pandas dataframe and result in true if the value is greater than median and false if value is less than median?

Right now I am standardizing, so basically comparing to 0 ( the mean ) of each column. Want a way to do the same for median.

Comment: add code which you have tried

Answer (score 3):

What I have understand from your question is you want to compare each column value from its column median

1. **.median()** to find median of column and save in column
2. **.apply(axis=1)** with **axis=1** to compare each value with value median()

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,2,3,4,4,5],
                        'b':[1,2,3,3,3,3]})
# median of col a and col b is calculated and save in another column
df['median_a'] = df['a'].median()
df['median_b'] = df['b'].median()

# if col a value is greater than median_a then a_bool contains True else False
df['a_bool']  = df.apply(lambda  x: True if x['a']>x['median_a'] else False ,axis=1)
df['b_bool']  = df.apply(lambda  x: True if x['b']>x['median_b'] else False,axis=1)
```

I hope it would solve your problem

Comment: I wanted it to be column agnostic, here you have to pre-define medians for columns a and b, rather I was looking for an column agnostic method that could be applied to all the columns in a dataframe

Comment: you can do this by having a list of columns and doing all this in a loop

Comment: update your question with example and expected output otherwise no one would be able to answer your question properly

Comment: @tawab_shakeel is there any way of getting the same result without creating a column for the mean and using apply?